# SQLAlchemy/MySQL binary blob is being utf-8 encoded?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, utf-8, sqlalchemy, blob

I'm using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and MySQL, with a `files` table to store files. That table is defined as follows:

```
mysql> show full columns in files;
+---------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field   | Type         | Collation       | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id      | varchar(32)  | utf8_general_ci | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| created | datetime     | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| updated | datetime     | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| content | mediumblob   | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| name    | varchar(500) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

The content column of type `MEDIUMBLOB` is where the files are stored. In SQLAlchemy that column is declared as:

```
__maxsize__ = 12582912 # 12MiB                                                                                                                              
content = Column(LargeBinary(length=__maxsize__))
```

I am not quite sure about the difference between SQLAlchemy's [`BINARY`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.BINARY) type and [`LargeBinary`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary) type. Or the difference between MySQL's [`VARBINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) type and [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) type. And I am not quite sure if that matters here.

**Question:** Whenever I store an actual binary file in that table, i.e. a Python [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) or `b''` object , then I get the following warning

```
.../python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:451: Warning: Invalid utf8 character string: 'BCB121'
  cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

I don't want to just ignore the warning, but it seems that the files are in tact. How do I handle this warning gracefully, how can I fix its cause?

**Side note:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734812/is-a-blob-converted-using-the-current-default-charset-in-mysql) seems to be related, and it seems to be a MySQL bug that it tries to convert *all* incoming data to UTF-8 ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734812/is-a-blob-converted-using-the-current-default-charset-in-mysql#14745685)).

Comment: You seem to be running Python.  The two "Side notes" refer to PHP and Perl issues.  Something in _Python_ is failing to honor your request to use "blob" data.

Comment: @RickJames: Yes, all Python. The "[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734812/is-a-blob-converted-using-the-current-default-charset-in-mysql#14745685)" link in the Side note, however, seems to indicate this to be a MySQL issue. If this is a Python issue though, I'd still like to understand what I'm missing here...

Comment: If the _client_ (PHP, Python, etc) treats the string as "characters", then this problem can arise.  If it treats it as arbitrary "bytes", then the problem does not occur.  Storing into a MySQL `BLOB` does no utf8 checking; storing into a `TEXT` does.

Comment: So, I claim, some detail _in the client_ is missing.  (Or Alchemy fails to handle `BLOBs`.)

Comment: @RickJames: it's a `b' '` objects, i.e. binary bytes...

Comment: Which MySQL driver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was a driver issue. Apparently the default MySQL driver stumbles with Py3 and utf8 support. Installing [cymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cymysql) into the virtual Python environment resolved this problem and the warnings disappear.

**The fix:** Find out if MySQL connects through socket or port (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885164/pymysql-cant-connect-to-mysql-on-localhost#14351678)), and then modify the connection string accordingly. In my case using a socket connection:

```
mysql+cymysql://user:pwd@localhost/database?unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Use the `port` argument otherwise.

**Edit:** While the above fixed the encoding issue, it gave rise to another one: blob size. Due to [a bug in CyMySQL](https://github.com/nakagami/CyMySQL/issues/13) blobs larger than 8M fail to commit. Switching to [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) fixed that problem, although it seems to have a [similar issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/397) with large blobs.

Comment: Actually, it is apparently the MySQL server that is generating this warning, and the way around it is to use `_binary` to say that the thing you're inserting should not be interpreted.  See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79317

Comment: @Wodin: which means to add `binary_prefix=true` to the connect string, see also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/am2cd2Cn41M).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but your problem might have the same roots as the one I had several years ago in python 2.7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535736/68998. In short, Mysql's interface does not let you be certain if you are working with a true binary string or a text in a binary collation (used because of a lack of case-sensitive utf8 collation). Therefore, a Mysql binding has the following options:

- return all string fields as binary strings, and leave the decoding to you
- decode only the fields that do not have a binary flag (so much fun when some of the fields are `unicode` and other are `str`)
- have an option to force decoding to `unicode` for all string fields, even true binary

My guess is that in your case, the third option is somewhere enabled in the underlying Mysql binding. And the first suspect is your connection string (connection params).

Comment: My current connection string is: `mysql://user@localhost/database?charset=utf8`. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) the `charset` option “Specifies the character set that should be used to encode all queries sent to the server.” Hmm—encode *all* queries?